# TypeVar class references in Sphinx docs, using Autodoc and Autodoc Typehints

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, type-hinting, autodoc

I'm working on the docs of my project and struggling to get internal classes properly referenced in the output files produced by Sphinx.

Below my project structure:

```
project/
|-- docs/
|   |-- build/
|   |-- source/
|       |-- conf.py
|       |-- index.rst
|       |-- ...
|-- mymodule/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- custom_types.py
|   |-- functions.py
|   |-- myclass.py
|-- README.md
|-- setup.cfg
|-- setup.py
```

In `myclass.py` I defined a class I want to document:

```
class MyClass:
  ...
```

In `custom_types.py` I defined a `TypeVar` reference to my class that I can in all my code files to type hint my class when necessary:

```
from typing import (
  TypeVar as _tp_TypeVar
)

tmc = _tp_TypeVar('MyClass')
```

Now, in `functions.py`, for example, I can use the TypeVar reference to create type hints whenever an imput argument must be of type `MyClass`:

```
from .custom_types import (
  tmc as _tmc
)

def do_something(obj: _tmc, steps: int):
  ...
```

On the point of view of IDE intellisense, everything works like a charm. If I place my cursor over the function definition, or any function call in my code, I see:

```
def do_something(obj: MyClass, steps: int)
  *docstring*
```

However, when I build the docs using `Sphinx`, this is what I get (TypeVar has a link to https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar while MyClass is just plain text with no link):

[image]

Long time ago, when I first started using `Sphinx` to build the docs of my project, this same setup was producing a much better outcome (`MyClass` had a link to the page where my class was documented):

[image]

Maybe something changed in the latest versions of `Sphinx`? How can I fix that so documents are produced like before?

By the way, my `conf.py` file loads the following extensions:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx_autodoc_typehints',
    'sphinx_rtd_theme'
]
```

Comment: Can you explain why use alias `_tp_TypeVar` and put the import alias in parenthesis like `from import (tmc as _tmc)`? (I've never seen the later syntax). There are several reasons why `MyClass` can show as red, the most likely reason is that it's not been inserted in the index (can you check if it's there)?

Comment: @bad_coder just some syntax to avoid referencing whole modules, by the way, yes, MyClass definately shows up in the index.

Comment: Likely the same bug reported 2 days ago on GitHub, see [Use of TypeVar results in "reference target not found" error](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10974).